# hbase.MasterNotRunningException while creating table in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times
```

I got this error when I am creating the table in HBase. I am giving like in following way to create the table by using HBase. I type the following  command on console.

```
create 'test', 'cf'
```

I got the above mentioned error. What would be the reasons for getting this error?
I am trying this table in standalone system.

Comment: Generally, it means hbase did not start correctly. Hbase might not be configured correctly. I have also seen it fail to start correctly when I started hbase too soon after starting hdfs. hdfs needs to be out of safe mode before starting hbase.

Comment: I see this also, when trying to run hbase in standalone mode on a fresh Ubuntu/hbase install.  Followed the directions here: http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html.  On the 'create' command described in section 1.2.3, got the MasterNotRunningException.

Comment: What do HBase logs say?

Answer (score 3):

this happens only if your namenode is in safe mode, so just enter the following command :- ***`hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`***

this command worked for me all ways, try it for you.

Answer (score 1):

you should check hadoop and hbase logs. it seems hdfs does not started correctly. as codingFoo said you should wait about 1 minute after starting hdfs before starting hbase. after starting hbase check http://:60010 to see what is going on in your machines

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exactly same error. After spending lots of hours struggling, it is finally resolved just by writing 'ubuntu' besides hostname in the /etc/hosts file.
i.e. 127.0.0.1 your-hostname ubuntu.

Obviously, this solution might work for you only if you are using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem after installing Hbase & did the below steps.

Just in your terminal go to Hbase->bin & run start-hbase.sh shown below .

user@client:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ start-hbase.sh

Then type jps in your terminal .Now HMaster will active .

user@client:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ jps

After this I could create a table .

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and as said I did `$start-hbase.sh` and then found the below processes by JPS command.

```
3420 TaskTracker
3202 SecondaryNameNode
2953 NameNode
4327 HRegionServer
4041 HQuorumPeer
4143 HMaster
3078 DataNode
4619 Jps
3290 JobTracker
```

Both hmaster hregionserver are ready. Now I am able to use hbase correctly.